# Question about error handeling in istream

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

This is an operator which is defined in *Programming: Principles and Practice Using C++* book. I have two questions. First, why after detecting an invalid format we set a failbit? Second, why after the user input an invalid format for the date and while `cin` is in the fail state, the date is constructed by default constructor?

```
istream& operator>>(istream& is, date& dd)
{
    int y, m, d;
    char ch1, ch2, ch3, ch4;
    is >> ch1 >> d >> ch2 >> m >> ch3 >> y >> ch4;
    if (!is) return is;
    if (ch1 != '(' || ch2 != ',' || ch3 != ',' || ch4 != ')') { // oops: format error
        is.clear(ios_base::failbit);
        return is;
    }
    dd = date{ d,m,y }; // update dd
    return is;
}
```

Comment: `Second, why after the user input an invalid format for the date and while cin is in the fail state, the date is constructed by default constructor?` Your code does not default-construct a date anywhere.

Comment: @tkausl In the date class, there is a default constructor.

Comment: But your function doesn't use the default constructor.

Comment: @tkausl this my code `date obj;
  cin >> obj;
  cout << '(' << obj.get_day() << ',' << obj.get_month() << ',' << obj.get_year() << ')'<<endl;` when the c++ shows the output it shows default date

Comment: `date obj;` default-constructs the object.

Comment: What @tkausl said. The `dd` argument is  default-constructed before you call the routine, because if the extraction fails, `dd` is never modified by your `operator>>`.

Comment: @Spencer If I delete `is.clear(ios_base::failbit);` and I input an invalid format date, `cin` doesn't modify `dd`. So what's the difference between including  `is.clear(ios_base::failbit);` and not including it?

Comment: *"So what's the difference between including `is.clear(ios_base::failbit);` and not including it?"* The difference is that `failbit` will be cleared in one case, and won't be cleared in the other, of course.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I understand but what is the advantage of setting the stream to fail state?

Comment: You are not setting the fail state, you are clearing it. The stream sets `failbit` when an extraction operation fails - e.g. when you try to read an integer but the content of the stream cannot be parsed as one. That's how it lets you know that the operation has failed.

Comment: @Swordfish I don't know the detail. I just copy the codes from the book. Page 365

Comment: @AmirTavakkoli sorry, i was totally wrong. it indeed sets the failbit. sorry :/

Comment: Amir, @Swordfish is correct, but in any case, you're `return`ing before  the routine can modify `dd`. So its state is the same as when you passed it in to the routine.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik is btw also wrong with his comments `is.clear(ios_base::failbit);` sets the failbit.

Comment: @Swordfish Igor is correct about the state being cleared.  `clear(failbit)` does indeed set `failbit`, but only after clearlinh all of the other bits, which is incorrect because it also clears `eofbit`. You were right about using `setstate` rather than `clear`.

Comment: @Spencer Correct me if I'm wrong. When I'm entering `cin`, the state is good. If I don't include a failbit, it will return but after executing `cin` the state is good as before. We want to set the state to fail if we hit a format error so we include failbit and in this case, after executing `cin` the state is fail.

Comment: @Amir `clear` is counterintuitive because, perversely, it sets bits. And `goodbit` isn't actually a bit, it's a zero value.

Comment: @Spencer Good point! So it should better be `is.clear(is.rdstate() | ios_base::failbit);`

Comment: @Swordfish or just use `setstate`.It OR's in the state bits.

Comment: @Spencer please, stop it :( you make me feel more incompetent with every comment of yours :(

Comment: @Spencer Yes, thanks to you and the others I found that I need to use `setstate` instead of `clear`. Did I understand my problem correctly in my previous comment?

Comment: @AmirTavakkoli yes

Comment: Yes, and with the same caveat about the state-setting function, the answer you accepted explains this well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First question. To inform the next function using your current stream that something went wrong the function sets a new value for the stream's internal error state flags.

```
is.clear(ios_base::failbit);
```

This way you can check after using operator >> that all went well using function

```
.fail()
```

of istream

for more info check out [fail](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/fail/) and [clear](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/clear/).

Second question. Your code does not call the default constructor, it just does not modify `dd` therefore if you coded something like

```
std::ifstream f('date.in')
date d;
f >> d;
if(!f.fail())
{ std::cout << d << std::endl;}
else
{ std::cout << "parsing failed" << std::endl;}
```

if f.fail() is true then d is unchanged and was instantiated using the default constructor.

Comment: We went on at length in the comments to OP about how `clear` is the wrong function to use because it clears `eofbit` and `badbit` at the same time it sets `failbit`. `setstate` should be used instead.

Comment: Whether to use `clear` or `setstate` is not the question. The question is why in this example of Programming: Principles and Practice Using C++ book do they use the clear function. After that it is every programmer for themselves...

Comment: In that case, I'm eating the whole pizza.

Comment: I am not a native English speaker. I think I get the meaning of the expression "I'm eating the whole pizza" and I like it already but could you ellaborate just to be sure I don't misinterpret it.

Comment: "After that, it's every programmer for themselves..." :D

Comment: Nice ! I'll remember it.